# How to drop many columns in table in oracle when columns are very large?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table and the table consists of 70 columns.I want to drop about 68 columns and i just want 2 columns in my table.So,whatever I tried is given below:

```
Alter table_name drop column where column
_name not in (col1, col2);
```

I found this step is time consuming. Is there any other better option where I can delete 68 columns without getting much time engaged?

Comment: Just create the new table with the 2 remaining columns, copy over the data from those two columns, and then drop the original table?

Comment: I would suggest to delete 68 columns because you will need to recreate indexes and referential constraint wherever PK of this table is used and trigger and blah blah. That will be again time consuming if table is large.

Comment: I would [set them unused](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dropping-columns) and then drop them all at once at some convenient time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script to generate the DDL to save typing.

```
CREATE TABLE test_drop ( a number, b number, c number, d number, e number);

select 'alter table ' || owner || '.' || table_Name || ' drop column ' || listagg(column_name,',') within group ( order by column_name) || ';' drop_ddl
from dba_tab_columns 
where owner = user
and table_Name = 'TEST_DROP'
and column_Name not in ('A','B')
group by owner, table_name;
```

> ```
> +-----------------------------------------------+
> |                 DROP_DDL                      |
> +-----------------------------------------------+
> | alter table APPS.TEST_DROP drop column C,D,E; |
> +-----------------------------------------------+
> ```

Then copy the output to and you have your DDL.  Recreating the table is an unnecessary pain.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new table with a SELECT: CREATE new_table AS SELECT col1, col2 FROM old_table

Drop the old table (use the purge option if you don't want it in the recycle bin)

Rename the new table to the old table name: RENAME new_table TO old_table

You'll also need to add back any indexes, triggers, constraints or grants that you had on the old table if you want them on the new table.